# Abrir uma imagem em lightbox no mesmo layout a partir de um botão

Tags: javascript, android, imagem

Bom dia, pessoal.
Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver, já fucei bastante nas postagens aqui e nos tutoriais do youtube e nada.
Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android para um projeto na faculdade, mas não sou programador, decidi pelo app para aprender mesmo.

O que eu preciso é abrir uma imagem que está no drawable em uma lightbox ao clicar em um botão.

esse é o meu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.editoratracos.jogotracos.hd"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo"
    android:id="@+id/telahd"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botaoNovo3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="chamaNovo"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/novojogo"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botaoComo2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="chamaComo"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/comojogar"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botaoHome"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home"
        android:onClick="chamaHome"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconAla"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ala"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iconAyao"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconAyao"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ayao"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iconBunzi"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconBunzi"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/bunzi"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconGleti"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/gleti"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iconBunzi"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconIemanja"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/iemanja"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iconGleti"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconMbaba"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mbaba"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iconAla"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/iconAla"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

           </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

e essa é a minha classe:

```
package com.editoratracos.jogotracos;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class hd extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, hd.class));
        finishAffinity();

        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hd);
    }
    public void chamaComo(View v) {setContentView(R.layout.activity_como);}
    public void chamaHD(View v) {setContentView(R.layout.activity_hd);}
    public void chamaNovo (View v) {setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo);}
    public void chamaSobre (View v) {setContentView(R.layout.activity_sobre);}
    public void chamaComecar (View v) {setContentView(R.layout.activity_comecar);}
    public void chamaHome (View v) {setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicial);}
}
```

Comment: Estou disposto a ajudar, mas ainda não entendi o que seria uma lightbox, pode explicar um pouco mais? é um componente? Ainda não posso comentar..

Comment: Boa tarde, LSA!

Lightbox é aquele modo visualização de imagem onde a mesma abre na mesma tela por cima dos demais elementos. Achei esse código no github, mas ele é um jQuery, não sei implementar em um projeto android:

https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/

Comment: @LSA é, trocando em miúdos, uma dialog que vai exibir a imagem em tamanho maior, podendo mostrar todos os detalhes dela, com zoom e tauz.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma, crie uma Activity com fundo transparente coloque o componente imageView e textView em baixo, e na hora que você clicar na foto, você inicia essa Activity ("TransparenteActivity") passando os dados da imagem com o

```
nome_da_intent.putExtra("img", "teste")
```

e pega na outra Activity com o

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String img = bundle.getString("img");
```

e depois coloca ela na imageView e a legenda no textView ou se preferir algo mais simples você pode utilizar o AlertDialog, segue a documentação nesse link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox é um plugin (jQuery) exclusivo para uso em páginas web (HTML), você não vai conseguir utilizar esse plugin em Linguagem Java.